# Writing a simple Gedit plug-in

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

I love Gedit and use it daily, but there's one simple thing that would make my work so much simpler. And that is being able to use the arrow keys to open and close directories in the File Browser in the Side Panel instead of having to try and hit that tiny little arrow with my wonky mousepad every time.

I can't imagine this being especially difficult to add, but I'm a web developer with zero knowledge of Linux development so I don't even know where to start.

So I was hoping you guys could point me in the right direction. Perhaps a simple XML file with keyboard shortcuts is all I need to edit? Or maybe a plug-in already exists? Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of gedit are you using? In mine, you can use the arrow keys to browse the filesystem. Press TAB or Shift-TAB to move the highlight to the area that contains folders and files and then up and down arrows. Press space to go into a directory. Use shift-TAB (just because its faster, you can use TAB if you prefer) to highlight the area at the top-left that shows the current directory,  and press space again to go to the directory you selected.
Hope This helps

Comment: I am using 3.10.4. And yea, I can navigate the files and folders using arrow keys up and down, and I can use enter or space to open a folder. What I would like to be able to do, though, is use the left and right arrow keys to expand and minimize folders (same thing that happens when you click the little arrow).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to switch from the editor to the side panel/file browser using Tab or Shift+Tab though. Obviously Tab just adds a tab to the document and Shift+Tab doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: if you are on the editor window press shift-ctrl-TAB to move to the browser window first. To expand a directory press + (shift = on my keyboard) and to reduce it -

Comment: Aaaah awesome! + and - does it. Any way to change those to right/left arrow? (PS. Ctrl+Shift+Tab doesn't work for me tho, but expanding folders was my biggest request)

Comment: Sorry, I dont know of any way to change the keys at the moment.